# How to map each i-th element of a dataframe to a key from another dataframe defined by ranges in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, left-join, between

### what I want to do

Transform the input file df0 into the desired output df2 based on the clustering define in df1

### What I have

```
df0 = spark.createDataFrame(
[('A',0.05),('B',0.01),('C',0.75),('D',1.05),('E',0.00),('F',0.95),('G',0.34), ('H',0.13)],
("items","quotient")
)

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
[('C0',0.00,0.00),('C1',0.01,0.05),('C2',0.06,0.10), ('C3',0.11,0.30), ('C4',0.31,0.50), ('C5',0.51,99.99)],
("cluster","from","to")
)
```

### What I want

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
[('A',0.05,'C1'),('B',0.01,'C1'),('C',0.75,'C5'),('D',1.05,'C5'),('E',0.00,'C0'),('F',0.95,'C3'),('G',0.34,'C2'), ('H',0.13,'C4')],
("items","quotient","cluster")
)
```

### notes

the coding environment is PySpark within Palantir.

the structure and content of DataFrame df1 can be adjusted for the sake of simplification in coding: df1 is what tells which cluster the items from df0 should be linked to.

---

*Thank you very in advance for your time and feedback !*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple left join problem.

```
df0.join(df1, df0['quotient'].between(df1['from'], df1['to']), "left") \
  .select(*df0.columns, df1['cluster']).show()

+-----+--------+-------+
|items|quotient|cluster|
+-----+--------+-------+
|    A|    0.05|     C1|
|    B|    0.01|     C1|
|    C|    0.75|     C5|
|    D|    1.05|     C5|
|    E|     0.0|     C0|
|    F|    0.95|     C5|
|    G|    0.34|     C4|
|    H|    0.13|     C3|
+-----+--------+-------+
```

Comment: thank you @Lamanus - I did not try to use the boolean expression .between() in that way. That is very simple indeed.